# Symbol for "Take Highest Number"

Tags: logic, notation

As the title states, is there a symbol for taking the highest value?

Let's say we have two variables $a=2$ and $b=3$ now I want $aXb$ (where $X$ is the symbol I am looking for) and I want that answer in this case to be $b$.

Comment: $\!\!\max(a,b)$?

Comment: That would work. I was looking if there were an arithmetic symbol like `+`, `-` and so on.

Comment: Well you have the symbol $\lor$ for joins in lattices, but the notation $\text{max}(a,b)$ is more common.

Comment: Doesn't `∨` mean or? While `/\\` means and?

Comment: $\vee$ can mean "logical or" while $\wedge$ can mean "logical and".  But there is such a thing as operator overloading in mathematics.

Comment: In this context I think $\vee$ is appropriate.

Comment: BTW, for some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: Although $a\vee b$ for the max is formally correct, it would be annoyingly pedantic, in my view, to use it instead of the far commoner $\max(a,b)$.